# Can't import torch in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

System: macOS 10.13.6
Python: 3.7
Anaconda3

I have trouble when `import torch` in jupyter notebook.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Here is how I install pytorch:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

I've checked PyTorch is installed in my anaconda environment:

[image]

When I command `python3` in my terminal and `import torch`, it works. But not work in jupyter notebook

I've tried:

```
conda update conda
conda install mkl=2018
```

But still the same error.

Comment: you should install jupyter notebook before you install pytorch.  what's your install order?

Comment: Do you use different kernels in jupyter notebook (Kernel -> Change kernel)?

Comment: @Alpha I install jupyter notebook before install PyTorch.

Comment: @yascho I have python2 and python3. But when I new a jupyter notebook, I only can choose python3, because python2 shows kernel error when I opened.

Answer (score 9):

You have to install `jupyter` in addition to `pytorch` inside your activated conda env. Here is installation steps:

### 1. Create conda env

for example: `pytorch_p37` with `python 3.7`:

```
user@pc:~$ conda create -n pytorch_p37 python=3.7
```

### 2. Activate it

```
user@pc:~$ conda activate pytorch_p37
```

Or with (for older `conda` versions):

```
user@pc:~$ source activate pytorch_p37
```

Now you should see `(pytorch_p37)` before your shell prompt:

```
(pytorch_p37) user@pc:~$
```

### 3. Go to [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/) and choose appropriate installation command via `conda`. Run it in your shell, for example

```
(pytorch_p37) user@pc:~$ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

### 4. Install `jupyter` inside your activated env as well

```
(pytorch_p37) user@pc:~$ conda install jupyter
```

### 5. Verify the installation

```
(pytorch_p37) user@pc:~$ conda list

# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37:
#
# Name
...
jupyter                   1.0.0  
jupyter_client            5.3.1  
jupyter_console           6.0.0 
jupyter_core              4.5.0
...
python                    3.7.4
pytorch                   1.2.0
...
```

### 6. Run `jupyter`

```
(pytorch_p37) user@pc:~$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I follow your steps, but still the same error :(

Comment: Hmm... what about `conda install mkl=2018`? I didn't add this line, can you try it?

Comment: No... still the same error. In the pytorch_p37 environment, I type: `python --version`, and the result is Python 3.7.4 instead of `Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) ` <-- I copy this from another web. Does it matter?

Comment: Python looks fine. the last hope on `conda update conda`, maybe it's a conda problem, if you have time and patience :) you сan try `conda update conda` then repeat all the steps (also with mkl)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where the jupyter lab couldn't import torch after successful installation in my virtual environment. But when I checked the list of installed packages using `conda list`, PyTorch was present but not jupyterlab. After installing jupyterlab, it is working fine!.

Comment: You are right! Thanks, By making sure my environment is activate then I install torch and then Jupyiter notebook fixes the `torch` module not fund issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same bug. I tried the following line on anaconda command prompt.

`(pytorch)C:\Users\user> conda install jupyter`

Then, I used the command `C:\Users\user> jupyter notebook` which launched the Jupyter notebook, and the *import torch* keyword started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the problem. My environment is that windows10, conda 4.8.3, and python 3.8.3.
Here are what I do,

1. Enter anaconda prompt shell and activate a environment of anoconda. My environment is pytorch.

`activate pytorch`

2. Create a kernel for Jupyter notebook in anoconda prompt shell for linking the environment of anoconda to a Jupyter notebook's kernel.

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name pytorch --display-name "pytorch"`

The first pytorch is the name of environment of anoconda, the second is the name of kernel of Jupyter notebook. Make sure ipykernel installed.

3.Run Jupyter notebook, select the kernel you just created in step 2, then import the module of torch to see the result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izKzJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved this problem by runing `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch` on **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**.

### Actual Result

```
(base) PS C:\Users\TayyabChaudhary> conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\TayyabChaudhary\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pytorch
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2021.9.30  |       haa95532_1         116 KB
    certifi-2021.10.8          |   py38haa95532_0         152 KB
    conda-4.10.3               |   py38haa95532_0         2.9 MB
    cudatoolkit-11.3.1         |       h59b6b97_2       545.3 MB
    libuv-1.40.0               |       he774522_0         255 KB
    openssl-1.1.1l             |       h2bbff1b_0         4.8 MB
    pytorch-1.10.0             |py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8_0        1.44 GB  pytorch
    pytorch-mutex-1.0          |             cuda           3 KB  pytorch
    torchvision-0.11.1         |       py38_cu113         8.8 MB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        1.99 GB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cudatoolkit        pkgs/main/win-64::cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h59b6b97_2
  libuv              pkgs/main/win-64::libuv-1.40.0-he774522_0
  pytorch            pytorch/win-64::pytorch-1.10.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8_0
  pytorch-mutex      pytorch/noarch::pytorch-mutex-1.0-cuda
  torchvision        pytorch/win-64::torchvision-0.11.1-py38_cu113

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    anaconda::ca-certificates-2020.10.14-0 --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2021.9.30-haa95532_1
  certifi                anaconda::certifi-2020.6.20-py38_0 --> pkgs/main::certifi-2021.10.8-py38haa95532_0
  conda                               4.10.1-py38haa95532_1 --> 4.10.3-py38haa95532_0
  openssl                                 1.1.1k-h2bbff1b_0 --> 1.1.1l-h2bbff1b_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
libuv-1.40.0         | 255 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
torchvision-0.11.1   | 8.8 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
certifi-2021.10.8    | 152 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
cudatoolkit-11.3.1   | 545.3 MB  | ############################################################################ | 100%
openssl-1.1.1l       | 4.8 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytorch-1.10.0       | 1.44 GB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
conda-4.10.3         | 2.9 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
ca-certificates-2021 | 116 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytorch-mutex-1.0    | 3 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NONFz.png)Personllay, I have tried different solutions and it solves my problem.
First, enter anaconda prompt and use the command `conda install nb_conda`.
Second, enter the env of pytorch and use `conda install ipykernel`.
After this, we can find in jupyter notebook, we have more language to use. Choose the language `Python [conda env:conda-pytorch]`, then we can run code using pytorch successfully.
Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I understand creating a virtual environment is an ideal approach but by installing a jupyter notebook extension in VSCode helped me solve this issue. I did not have to create a virtual environment (This depends on the user if they have to create one or not)

Comment: Irrelevant information. It has noting to do with VS Code extension. It works as long as Jupyter uses the same python, no matter default python or env, which installed torch.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by recreating the venv, conda installing jupyterlab inside the venv and running pip install instead of conda in the jupyter lab session.

```
conda deactivate [venv_name]
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=[venv_name]
conda remove -n [venv_name] --all
conda create -n [venv_name] python=3.9
conda activate [venv_name]
conda install jupyterlab
jupyter lab
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

(check pytorch for specific command depending on cuda version, etc.)
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/