# torch virtual env not working python 3.7 , what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, terminal, pytorch

so i installed pytorch using conda into a virtual env while referring to this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBfM5l9VK5c

i have activated the env

now inside jupyter notebook i run

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

and it works but when ever i run this in .py file and run it through terminal it gives me this error

```
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

if I try to pip install pytorch it says

```
 Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in c:\users\kiit\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\kiit\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.9.0 in c:\users\kiit\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=5.3.0 in c:\users\kiit\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions in c:\users\kiit\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.9.0->torchvision) (3.7.4.3)
```

so what is going on exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have more than one python versions installed on your system i.e One with conda and one separately.
In order to check that, you can go to control panel --> Programs and features. There you can figure out how many python installations are present on your system. Delete the one you dont need and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer that could be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57753725
Credits to [trsvchn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10749432/trsvchn) for the above answer link.

Perhaps also try opening jupyter notebook from the command line if that doesn't work.

Comment: no problem with jupyter notebooks , there the torch works fine  the problem is when i run torch via say an ide like spyder or vs code it gives me no module error

Comment: Perhaps the answer above could work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062740/14428026, credit to Harris Minhas